# h5p-standalone with ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, h5p

I'm currently trying to implement package [h5p-standalone](https://github.com/tunapanda/h5p-standalone) with ReactJS

Below is my code

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import { H5P } from "h5p-standalone";

function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    const el = document.getElementById("h5p-container");

    const options = {
      h5pJsonPath: "h5p-folder",
      frameJs: "h5p-assets/frame.bundle.js",
      frameCss: "h5p-assets/styles/h5p.css",
    };

    const h5p = new H5P(el, options);

    h5p.then((res) => console.log(res)).catch((e) => console.log("Err: ", e));
  }, []);

  return <div id="h5p-container"></div>;
}

export default App;
```

But when I run and check browser console it shows:

`Err:  SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON`

[My project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzzHU.png)

Is there any step that I did wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The error message is most likely hinting to a 404 page that your server sent, just have a look at your network tab.

I assume you did not put any H5P content into the `h5p-folder`, so h5p-standalone cannot find the `h5p.json` file that would tell what resources to use.

Comment: h5pJsonPath: "h5p-folder" -> that might be wrong?

Comment: @DiegoGonzálezCruz If content was served in some other folder, then `h5pJsonPath` would need to point to that folder, sure. But given that the OP seems to be using the default configuration and most likely never got this running before in the first, it's unlikely that he/she wanted to use a different folder and just forgot to change the setting.

Answer (score -1):

if you look at your h5p json files, they contain the following elements "<!DOCTYPE".(which are not json)

in your vs code search <!DOCTYPE, and in the json files that contain it delete  or comment them out.

that's how i solved it, as i got the same error.